# Can this be bypassed with SQL Injection?

Tags: authentication, php, sql-injection, mysql, account-security

This is my php code:

```
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = md5($_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$pwd'";
```

My friend gave me this code but I’d like to know if this is secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s ridiculously bad.

A username of `steve’ or password=‘` makes you be Steve.

And since it’s saving passwords as a simple MD5 it allows fast cracking with John the Ripper and friends if the database is leaked.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is just for a school project but our panels check this kind of things

Comment: Being a school project doesn’t really change the answer to “is it secure”. It is subject to SQL injection, unless mitigation’s (not present in your question) defend it. And defending is much harder than you’d think.